# Rails validate :if with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I am working with a form having 2 checkboxes: `option_one` and `option_two`.

I don't want to allow submission of the form if `option_two` is checked and `option_one` is not.

In other words if somebody checks `option_two`, they must check `option_one` as well.

So in my MyModel I wrote :

```
validates :option_one, :presence => true, :if => option_two_active?, :message => "Dummy message."
```

Then in the MyController, I added :

```
def option_two_active?
    params[:option_two] == "1"
end
```

But it keeps giving me the following error :

```
NoMethodError in MyController#index
```

Is my approach correct ? How can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the conditional method with a symbol:

```
validates :option_one, :presence => true, :if => :option_two_active?, :message => "Dummy message."
```

Also, you since you can't use `params` from a model, you should assign that value to the model from the controller, either with `create`, `update_attributes`, or manually. If you want to persist the `option_two` field, then it should be a database column, else you can just create an attribute accessor:

```
attribute_accessor :option_two
```

Comment: Thanks ! But now I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'params'`. How can I get the values from the form fields if I can not use 'params' ?

Comment: Yes, `option_two` is a db column. I am not sure if I understand this correct, but seems like your method is to write the values to the db and then read them, right ? Can't I read the form values in the model before writing them to the db ?

Comment: @Myxtic ActiveRecord handles the validation before the persistence by default. It will never persist to the database an invalid object. `create`, `update_attributes` and `save` will all fail when any of the validation conditions is not fulfilled. You should assign the values to your models to let ActiveRecord do it's work. More on validation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Answer (score 2):

The way you reference the method, it will be called directly as the class is first loaded. However, the `:if` parameter is expected to be used with either a proc which is then called during validation or with a symbol representing a method name. In your case, you should thus setup your validation like this:

```
validates :option_one, :presence => true, :if => :option_two?, :message => "Dummy message."
```

Notice the colon before the method name. Furthermor, the validation method needs to be defined on the model, not the controller. Fortunately, ActiveRecord already defines the proper methods for Boolean fields, as used here.

Comment: Thanks ! But when I define the method option_two_active? in the model, I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'params'`. How can I fix this ? My apologies for being a noob.

Comment: Yeah, the `params` hash is only available in a controller context, not in the model. Instead you should simply assign the params to the model and use the auto-generated methods there. Then you don't even need to define an additional method.